# DevExpress Code Indent Guidelines 11.2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, ide, devexpress, coderush-xpress

I've been using DevExpress's free refactoring tool for about 6 months now (love it!).  One of my favorite features is the code indent guidelines.

The other day I noticed they have released a new version so I upgraded (was on 11.1 and upgraded to 11.2).  After the upgrade the guidelines have vanished.  Is it possible to turn them back on in 11.2?  If so how do I do it?

(like bellow..)

[image: Just in case know one knows what I'm talking about here's a pic]

Comment: We (DevExpress) were informed of a similar issue in the past and have successfully fixed it with the next 11.2.9 minor release which is coming soon. I suggest you wait for this upcoming update and upgrade to a new version, so the guidelines work again for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m also using CodeRush XPress 11.2, but the lines are visible for me. Try to uninstall all versions of CodeRush XPress, and then install CodeRush XPress 11.2 again.

If you have any problems with CodeRush you should contact the [support](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/) of DevExpress. I had no problems with them and all bugs i reported where solved in the next version.

Comment: Thanks Jehof, I uninstalled 11.1 and reinstalled 11.2 and now they are appearing again!

Answer (score 1):

In Options, within Editor-Painting, enable Structural Highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

these coding lines are to do with JustCode i disabled the plug in as im not needing it anyway and they have gone away :)